# FreeBSD permissions issue

Tags: permissions, freebsd

I am slowly learning FreeBSD through a home server build and have run into a permissions issue that I can't seem to resolve despite a great deal of searching.

As my admin user "sadmin", when trying to rm -R a directory, I get permission denied. My user is in the group for all directories leading up to the directory I want to move. r-x is set for all parent directories. rwx is set for the directory I wish to rm. I am able run ls and cd in the entire file tree leading to the directory and I can change into the directory.

The file tree uses a group called autoagent, and sadmin is part of the autoagent group. I have logged out and logged back in to no effect.

Some output:

$ id

uid=1001(sadmin) gid=1001(sadmin) groups=1001(sadmin),0(wheel),**1002(autoagent)**

$ ls -l / | grep management

drwxr-xr-x   3 sadmin  autoagent   512 Jul  3 18:23 management

$ ls -l /management/

total 5092

drwxr-xr-x  5 sadmin  autoagent      512 Jul  3 18:32 nzbget

-rw-r--r--  1 sadmin  autoagent  5156582 Jul  3 18:22 nzbget-latest-bin-freebsd.run

$ ls -l /management/nzbget/ | grep downl

drwxr-xr-x  8 sadmin  autoagent      512 Jul  4 10:35 downloads

$ ls -l /management/nzbget/downloads/ | grep inter

drwxr-xr-x  3 root    autoagent        512 Jul  4 11:05 intermediate

$ ls -l /management/nzbget/downloads/intermediate/

total 4

drwx**rwx**r-x  2 root  autoagent  512 Jul  4 11:05 a12E3vdklK8KKdn

$ rm -R /management/nzbget/downloads/intermediate/a12E3vdklK8KKdn/
rm: /management/nzbget/downloads/intermediate/a12E3vdklK8KKdn/: Permission denied

I'm certain that I'm not handling permissions correctly, but I don't know what else to do.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to remove the file `a12E3vdklK8KKdn` you will need write access to the directory containing it. The file is being unlinked from the directory.

The directory `intermediate` only has `r-x` permission for the `autoagent` group.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I've never thought about the linking relationship between directories.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work#21252 , it you need further explanation of permission bits on directories